# Condition for Poncelet's porism for circles

Tags: geometry, circles, projective-geometry

> Prove for $n=1,2$ that if
> $$\frac{1}{(R+d)^n}+\frac{1}{(R-d)^n}=\frac{1}{r^n}$$
> where $R,r$ are the radii of two circles with the smaller one being inside the larger one and $d$ being the distance between their centers, then there is a $n+2$ - polygon inscribed in the smaller one and inscribing the larger one.
> Is this true for $n\geq 3$?

We know using Poncelet's porism it is enough to prove this happens for a polygon symmetric around the axis between the two centers and using that I've been able to calculate $n=1$ but $n=2$ was too complicated.
Is there a simpler way to see if it's correct?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_polygon and the corresponding references.

Comment: Try the easier case when $d=0$. If the statement is true for all $R,r,d$ then it should be true for $d=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following figure shows a bicentric quadrilateral that is symmetric about the line of centers $CO$, is inscribed in circle $(C)$, and touches the circle$(O)$.

[image: figure]

The following proof is excerpted from Johnson, *Advanced Euclidean Geometry*, 1929.  $R,r$ have been renamed to $r,\rho$ and $d=\overline{CO}$ (the length of segment $CO$).  The proof builds a system of similar right angled triangles and then ratio chases to derive the formula.

[image: PROOF]

Note that in the second last line the expression $OD=\dfrac{\rho^2}{r+d}$ comes from $OD\cdot OA_1=\rho^2$, which can be easily demonstrated using similar triangles. $A_1$ is the inverse of $D$ in circle $(O)$.  Similarly for the other expression.